# Scout does not seem to compile compass variables

Tags: sass, compass-sass, scout-sass

Its giving me ...

> syntax error: Undefined mixin

... when i input ...

```
*{
  @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

... in the scss file, and refresh my browser does anyone have a idea of what the problem could be.

I have previously installed ruby and compass through the command prompt i don't know if it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you declare before your mixin? To use variable you need to use `$` before it.
 try this:

```
@mixin box-sizing($border-box){
   //code
}

*{ 
    @include box-sizing($border-box); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixins must be declared (or imported if they are declared in another file) before you can use them.  Check the Compass documentation to find which file you need to import in order to use them:

```
@import "compass/css3/box-sizing";

* {
    @include box-sizing(border-box);
}
```

http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/box_sizing/